# iOS: Getting Cities/Counties between Start Location and End Destination Using Google Map or Directions API

Tags: ios, google-api

Hi Experts and Friends,

I have been searching for a solution for this seemingly simple task for days already, but I don't seem to have come across any useful approach.

Here is what I want:

Get my current location using CLLocation (ok here)
Get the final destination I enter (also ok here)
What I would like to accomplish is: get a list of cities in between these two points.
If the start location lies within the same city limit of the end destination, then simply show only that city in which the start location is.

EX: Current Location SF
Destination: Cupertino
Cities in between: Daly City, San Bruno, etc etc ....Santa Clara....Cupertino.

Is it possible to grab these from Google APIs? And am not talking about the "steps", because many steps can lie within a city limit, am only interested in cities (or county).

If so, which (v2.? v.3?) one? Or from Directions API? How are they different by the way? Am asking because different people seem to have different answers.

Thanks in advance. Regards.